# Choose 2 Random Values from 2 Separate Columns SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having to prepare test data to send to a 3rd party however I don't wish to send the customers real name nor do I wish to send their real date of birth.

I could solve the D.O.B issue by just randomly increasing the DOB by several years. However the name is different, is there anyway I can have a list of say 10 customer names and just choose a different Firstname and Surname each time.

I wish to mix and match the names however so it essentially randomly picks 1 firstname and then randomly picks a lastname and puts them together on the same line.

```
SELECT TOP 1 opde.first_name 
FROM Table AS opde
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This will return a random first name each time, but if I put the surname column in it will also return the matching surname, I don't want that I want a random surname from the list.

I tried doing this via a `UNION` but you can't do an `ORDER BY NEWID()` in the `UNION`.

Cheers.

Comment: Just remove the name column from the data you export.  Why would the 3rd party need it anyway?  A customer id, or hashed customer id, should be sufficient.

Comment: To me, just assorting real names is not good. It still leaks some info about customers you have. As does randomly changing just one component of the date of birth, etc. Think rare fore/surnames: divulging one of those could nearly conclusively identify someone, and then you also reveal that person's day and month of birth!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I guess that makes more sense, I could just place a placeholder in there and maybe just increment the surname with a number per row. JohnSmith1, John Smith2 etc.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Additionally I could just create a table of cartoon character names and use Tim's query below surely?

Comment: You could use a cross apply on the surname with newid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one might help...

```
WITH fn AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 opde.first_name
    FROM Table AS opde 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
),
sn AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 opde.surname
    FROM Table AS opde 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
SELECT first_name, surname
FROM fn
CROSS APPLY sn;
```

In the fn subquery you select a random first name. In the sn you do the same but with an surname.
With the cross apply you combine those two results

Comment: You might want to add a bit of explanation as well. Code-only answers are considered low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a union of subqueries, each of which uses order by with `NEWID`:

```
SELECT first_name
FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 opde.first_name FROM Table AS opde ORDER BY NEWID()) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT first_name
FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 opde.first_name FROM Table AS opde ORDER BY NEWID()) t2;
```

### Demo